# How to programatically detect if local and remote branches are different?

Tags: git

I have a master branch, and I want to have a script that detects if the remote master has updated. I know I can do this:

```
git fetch
```

And now when I run

```
git diff master origin/master
```

I get input.

The question is, is the best way to detect this in a script is to analyze the textual output? Feels not so stable.. Any ideas?

Comment: In a script you should use the lower level commands. Never rely on the human-friendly output of the higher level commands in a script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `--exit-code` option

```
if git diff --exit-code master origin/master > /dev/null; then
   echo "Up to date"
else
   echo "Differences found"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok I figured that I can use the commit hash to verify this:

```
$ LOCAL=$(git rev-parse master)
$ REMOTE=$(git rev-parse origin/master)
if ! [ $LOCAL == $REMOTE ]; then
    echo "Remote has updated"
fi
```

Comment: Note that comparing commit hashes is a valid way to find out if the two commits are the *same commit*. Comparing with `git diff --exit-code`, as in chepner's answer, gives you a different answer: do the two commits contain the same *code* (same snapshot)? If they are the same commit, they contain the same snapshot, but different commits might also contain the same snapshot.